# jquery plugin options not extending correctly and overwriting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange problem with the jquery plugin and options getting over written.

1. If I setup the plugin like this it [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/DAzfF/).

   ```
   $("#social-media").socialMedia({
       url: "http://css-tricks.com",
       social: [
           { name: "facebook", widget: "like_small" },
           { name: "twitter", widget: "small" },
           { name: "googlePlus", widget: "small" }
       ]    
   });
   ```
2. If I add a extra option that I need to overwrite, the [facebook like button does not load](http://jsfiddle.net/UwvDM/).

   ```
   $("#social-media").socialMedia({
       url: "http://css-tricks.com",
       social: [
           { name: "facebook", widget: "like_small" },
           { name: "twitter", widget: "small" },
           { name: "googlePlus", widget: "small" }
       ],
       facebook: {
           id: 195838043798363
       }     
   });
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) replaces whole properties. So, if the defaults have this:

```
{
    …
    facebook: {
        like_large: '<div class="fb-like" data-href="{url}" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="120" data-show-faces="false"></div>',
        like_small: '<div class="fb-like" data-href="{url}" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="120" data-height="21" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="light"></div>',
        share: '<a name="fb_share" type="box_count" share_url="{url}" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}&t={title}">Share</a>',
        id: 195838043798363
    },
    …
}
```

And your options look like this:

```
{
    …
    facebook: {
        id: 195838043798363
    }     
    …
}
```

The whole `facebook` object will be replaced with `{ id: 195838043798363 }`.

It turns out that [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) supports doing what you’re trying to get it to do, if you pass `true` as its first argument. Changing this line:

```
var opt = $.extend({},defaults, options);
```

to this:

```
var opt = $.extend(true, {},defaults, options);
```

Should make it do what you want it to do.

Comment: @Jivings Thanks for the jsfiddle! Actually, I like you answer better. Though mine is an easy fix, yours makes the design of the plugin better.

Answer (score 1):

With that assignment you are overwriting the entire `facebook` object in your plugin so that it only consists of the `id` variable.

You're best off making the facebook id a separate property to overwrite:

```
...
facebook:   {
    like_large: '<div class="fb-like" data-href="{url}" data-send="false" data-layout="box_count" data-width="120" data-show-faces="false"></div>',
    like_small: '<div class="fb-like" data-href="{url}" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="120" data-height="21" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="light"></div>',
    share: '<a name="fb_share" type="box_count" share_url="{url}" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}&t={title}">Share</a>',                   
},
facebook-id: 1000000, 
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UwvDM/3/